# ELB Target groups health checks are failing with 403 after upgrading from Rails 5 to rails 6

Tags: amazon-elb, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-upgrade

ELB target group's health check is failing with status code **403** forbidden after upgraded rails to **rails 6**. However health check is working in development but not on AWS cloud.

Health check is succeed with **rails 5** but not with **rails 6**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it fail right away? I'm having a very similar problem (ELB health check failing with 403 after upgrading from Rails 5 to Rails 6), but it happens only every 15 minutes or so. (Checking every 5 minutes, and healthy threshold is 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of a new feature in Rails 6: host authorization. It checks whether the incoming request has correct hostname, and in case it doesn't, it returns 403.

AWS ELB doesn't set the `Host` header when it accesses the health check endpoint, which makes it fail.

You can fix the problem either by disabling the feature (`config.hosts.clear`) by adding the web server internal IP (ELB accesses it with the internal one) to the allowed hosts, like this:

```
  config.hosts = ["example.org", IPAddr.new("10.0.99.0/24")]
```